# Is it possible to change JWT signing algorithm from RS256 to HS256 in OAuth 2.0 (Azure Active Directory)?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible to change the JWT signing algorithm from RS256 to HS256 for OAuth 2.0 in Azure Active Directory?

I am implementing an API to be called from a server that only supports HS256, HS384 and HS512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, AAD only supports RS256. There is no way to affect this.

You can check the metadata document e.g. here: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration.
It lists only RS256.

Answer (score 1):

As @juunas said AAD only supports RS256.

However, if you are using AAD B2C you create your own -for example- HS256 key using custom policy via the Identity Experience Framework.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy